# The tab key does not work when AutoComplete is in a editable DataTable

Tags: primefaces, datatable, autocomplete

I have a `p:autoComplete` inside a `p:dataTable` with `p:cellEditors`. when i push the tab key cursor correctly moves in order between the row elements , for example between inputs and selectOneMenus except AutoComplete, cursor go into AutoComplete but it can't exit from it.

I understood if i delete `var` in `p:autoComplete` it works correctly, i think `var` generate a hidden input that destroyed tabindex, but i can't fix it with tabindex and other ways.

```html
     <p:dataTable id="FieldSoftwareElement_listForm_dataTable"  value="#{classSoftwareElementController.selectedClassSoftwareElement.fields}" var="item" style="margin-top: 30px;margin-bottom: 10px"
                  widgetVar="itemWidgetVar" styleClass="editableDataTable"  selection="#{classSoftwareElementController.selectedFieldSoftwareElements}" editMode="cell" editable="true"
                  paginator="false" paginatorAlwaysVisible="false" paginatorPosition="bottom" rowKey="#{item.hashCode()}" rows="10" rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,30,40,50">
                    <p:ajax event="rowUnselectCheckbox" update="FieldSoftwareElement_listForm_btnsPanel"/>
                    <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:16px;text-align:center"/>

       <p:column  headerText="#{bundle.FieldSoftwareElement_AccessFlag}">
          <p:cellEditor>
                   <f:facet name="output">
                      <p:outputLabel  value="#{item.accessFlag}"/>
                   </f:facet>
                   <f:facet name="input" id="cfh">
                      <p:autoComplete styleClass="search-box" title="Creator"
                                    id="ReferenceEventDialog_referenceEventForm_toCreatorIn" multiple="true"
                                    var="creator"                                   
                                    value="#{item.accessFlag}"
                                    completeMethod="#{sendLtrView.allowableActors}"
                                    converter="ActorRelationConverter" itemLabel="#{creator.title}"
                                    itemValue="#{creator}"
                                    disabled="#{tabParam.readOnly}" forceSelection="true">
                   </f:facet>
         </p:cellEditor>
       </p:column>
       <p:column headerText="#{bundle.FieldSoftwareElement_ColumnSize}">
           <p:cellEditor>
                  <f:facet name="output">
                     <p:outputLabel value="#{item.columnSize}"/>
                  </f:facet>
                  <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:inputNumber value="#{item.columnSize}" disabled="#{not classSoftwareElementController.selectedDynamic}"/>
                  </f:facet>
         </p:cellEditor>
     </p:column>                                             
     </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: What version of PrimeFaces?

Comment: @Melloware version 7.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see this ticket: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/3314

It will be fixed in 7.1.  If you set `autoSelection="false"` on AutoComplete the TAB key will work like normal and not select the item.

Comment: I tested it in primefaces pure project and this is not worked for me,notice you my `p:autoComplete` in a `p:cellEditor` and without cellEditor i don't have problem .when i remove `var` in autocomplete tabkey works normal.

Comment: I am sorry you tested it against the 7.1 SNAPSHOT? with autoselection="false"?  It is not fixed in 7.0 only 7.1

Comment: your welcome, no i tested only in 7.0, i thought you said it fix in 7.0 with `autoSelection="false"` , ok so I will wait for 7.1.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, yes it is only fixed in 7.1.